# Is there a C# implementation of Redis-rdb-tools?

Tags: c#-4.0, redis, servicestack, booksleeve

Taking a look at [Redis-RDB-Tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools), it looks like there are some useful functions for monitoring the health of your Redis server.

[ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/#new-iredisclient-lua-apis) seems to have a good set of client functions (but I'm using [BookSleeve](http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/)).

Are there any C# implementations that give me some basic health checks - consumed memory, disk usage, etc?

**-- UPDATE --**

Thanks to BookSleeve's GetInfo() command, the following is returned... however I should have been more specific:  Is there a way of getting back the server info as parameters/object properties or a pre-packaged way of parsing the output values?

Here is the output from GetInfo():

```
"# Server\r\nredis_version:2.6.10\r\nredis_git_sha1:00000000\r\nredis_git_dirty:0\r\nredis_mode:standalone\r\nos:Linux 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64\r\narch_bits:64\r\nmultiplexing_api:epoll\r\ngcc_version:4.4.6\r\nprocess_id:2492\r\nrun_id:62402d583871f4b83f469917966aed8d163d02f3\r\ntcp_port:6379\r\nuptime_in_seconds:502354\r\nuptime_in_days:5\r\nlru_clock:1928056\r\n\r\n# Clients\r\nconnected_clients:7\r\nclient_longest_output_list:0\r\nclient_biggest_input_buf:175\r\nblocked_clients:0\r\n\r\n# Memory\r\nused_memory:1402576\r\nused_memory_human:1.34M\r\nused_memory_rss:9719808\r\nused_memory_peak:1675192\r\nused_memory_peak_human:1.60M\r\nused_memory_lua:31744\r\nmem_fragmentation_ratio:6.93\r\nmem_allocator:jemalloc-3.2.0\r\n\r\n# Persistence\r\nloading:0\r\nrdb_changes_since_last_save:3035\r\nrdb_bgsave_in_progress:0\r\nrdb_last_save_time:1360955487\r\nrdb_last_bgsave_status:ok\r\nrdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1\r\nrdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1\r\naof_enabled:0\r\naof_rewrite_in_progress:0\r\naof_rewrite_scheduled:0\r\naof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1\r\naof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1\r\naof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok\r\n\r\n# Stats\r\ntotal_connections_received:18822\r\ntotal_commands_processed:12547\r\ninstantaneous_ops_per_sec:3\r\nrejected_connections:0\r\nexpired_keys:0\r\nevicted_keys:0\r\nkeyspace_hits:374\r\nkeyspace_misses:39\r\npubsub_channels:1\r\npubsub_patterns:0\r\nlatest_fork_usec:0\r\n\r\n# Replication\r\nrole:master\r\nconnected_slaves:0\r\n\r\n# CPU\r\nused_cpu_sys:57.82\r\nused_cpu_user:208.63\r\nused_cpu_sys_children:0.00\r\nused_cpu_user_children:0.00\r\n\r\n# Keyspace\r\ndb0:keys=6,expires=0\r\n"
```

Comment: To expand: in BookSleeve the `GetInfo()` command on the connection instance returns this information

Comment: Updated question: Is there a way to read/process individual values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the updated question: the information there is not currently exposed as "parsed", but that sounds like a reasonable thing to add; I suspect I'll hide the `GetInfo()` method, move it to `.Server.GetInfo()`, and expose it in a parsed form. The code to split it already exists, though - but as a private method: `RedisConnectionBase.ParseInfo`:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> ParseInfo(string result)
{
    string[] lines = result.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string line = lines[i];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || line[0] == '#') continue; // 2.6+ can have empty lines, and comment lines
        int idx = line.IndexOf(':');
        if (idx > 0) // double check this line looks about right
        {
            data.Add(line.Substring(0, idx), line.Substring(idx + 1));
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, in parsed form, it makes more sense, as then the values will be usable, rather than merely just for display.

Comment: Refraining from modifying the BookSleeve code, I added the method to my helper class.  Works great, thanks.

Comment: @ElHaix my local copy now has (under `.Server`): `Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetInfo(string section = null, bool queueJump = false);`

Answer (score 1):

Call [Redis's INFO command](http://redis.io/commands/info), it provides all the different server info stats inside a redis-server.

Here's [a page dump of all the available stats](http://www.servicestack.net/RedisAdminUI/AjaxClient/) on a 2.5.12 version of redis-server.